# How to refer to assets coming from Razor Class Library from the server?

Tags: c#, blazor

My actual case -- because I am switching back and forth between Blazor servers I would like to put some shared assets in RCL library, in "wwwroot" folder. I can access given asset (image) from Blazor client, no problem, but now I would also to access them from the server side as well.

Previously, when I had the images directly in "wwwroot" of the server, it was no problem, both client and the server could access them. Once I moved images to the RCL, they are physically moved and I know how to refer to them from the client, but not from server. They re-appear within server reach when I publish solution, although not during "normal" development.

So how can refer to them from the server (in universal way)?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Blazor, but _in ye olden days_ with WebForms (2001-2008) "Server-Control Class Libraries" could bundle client-side assets as normal .NET resources (either inside a `.resx`/`.resources` collection - or as their own raw manifest resource streams) inside the library's main assembly `.dll` and they'd be referenced via a `GET` request to [the "magic" `WebResource.axd` handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318092/what-is-webresource-axd) built-in to ASP.NET - I assume a similar approach exists for Blazor, but if not, then you could try reimplementing your own equivalent

Comment: @Dai Nice :-) I prefer to keep them in "raw" form simply because server could list what is available (list of images) and client can put regular `<img src=...` to get just one of them, so it a matter of pure html markup.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,we could access the static files in RCL with the path format:

```
_content/{PACKAGE ID/ASSEMBLY NAME}/{PATH}/{FILE NAME}
```

Secondly,there's a trick to get the `fileprovider` from DI and may be the solution for you:

in a Razor Component(in my case, Index.razor in a default Balzor Server App):

```
@inject IServiceProvider _provider;
......

<img src=@PicPath />
......

@code{
    private string PicPath = "";


    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        var staticFileOptions = _provider.GetService<IOptions<StaticFileOptions>>();
        var provides = staticFileOptions?.Value.FileProvider;
        var contents = provides?.GetDirectoryContents("_content/RazorClassLibraryProj");
        PicPath = "_content/RazorClassLibraryProj/"+contents.Where(x=>x.Name.Contains("png")).FirstOrDefault()?.Name;

        base.OnInitialized();
    }
}
```

Now,the picture in RCL is rendered  correctly:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but you are describing Blazor client side. This part I know. I am asking about server (backend) side.

Comment: Since you've mentioned you are working with Blazor Server App. The codes in OnInitialized() is excuted on serverside ,here's a case related :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62179127/where-does-code-inside-of-code-runs-in-blazor-server-side

Comment: If I misunderstood your requirement,could you explain your requirement(I am asking about server (backend) side) more deatiled to me?

Comment: I rephrase -- I need to get access in uniform way from backend of Blazor Server, fronted of Blazor Server, backend of Blazor WebAsm, and fronted of Blazor WebAsm, both during development and once it is published. So far the problem lies in backend, frontend always work fine with "_content/...". With backend I added a hack -- I added a flag once the project is published. Once I detect it I access basically local asset, otherwise I traverse directories and get into RCL wwwroot directory.